# Associate a percentage value to each item in a data structure. The sum should be fixed

Tags: javascript

I've this dataset:

```js
const data = {
  catA: {
    color: ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'gold'],
    animal: ['cat', 'dog', 'hamster'],
  },
  catB: {
    city: ['Syndey', 'Paris', 'Rome', 'London', 'Tokyo', 'Delhi', 'Cairo']
  }
}
```

and what I would like to get is a similar data structure with a percentage value assigned to each element in the arrays. The sum of the percentage values should be 100.
Some elements could have value 0 and some not, is not important how many elements have percentage 0.

Below some examples of what I'm expecting:

```js
const res1 = {
  catA: {
    color: [['red', 0], ['blue', 10], ['yellow', 5], ['gold', 0]],
    animal: [['cat', 50], ['dog', 0], ['hamster', 5]],
  },
  catB: {
    city: [['Syndey', 20], ['Paris', 0], ['Rome', 0], ['London', 10], ['Tokyo', 0], ['Delhi', 0], ['Cairo', 0]]
  }
}

const res2 = {
  catA: {
    color: [['red', 100], ['blue', 0], ['yellow', 0], ['gold', 0]],
    animal: [['cat', 0], ['dog', 0], ['hamster', 0]],
  },
  catB: {
    city: [['Syndey', 0], ['Paris', 0], ['Rome', 0], ['London', 0], ['Tokyo', 0], ['Delhi', 0], ['Cairo', 0]]
  }
}

const res3 = {
  catA: {
    color: [['red', 60], ['blue', 0], ['yellow', 0], ['gold', 10]],
    animal: [['cat', 5], ['dog', 5], ['hamster', 20]],
  },
  catB: {
    city: [['Syndey', 5], ['Paris', 5], ['Rome', 10], ['London', 5], ['Tokyo', 0], ['Delhi', 5], ['Cairo', 10]]
  }
}
```

So I've created a function that returns an array of values whose sum is fixed:

```js
function randomNumbersWithFixedSum(quantity, sum) {
  if (quantity === 1) return [sum];
  const randomNum = _.random(0, sum);
  return [
    randomNum,
    ...randomNumbersWithFixedSum(quantity - 1, sum - randomNum),
  ];
}
```

`_.random` is a Lodash function.

Now, how can I create a function that returns a result similar to the ones before?

```js
const dataWithPercentages = addPercentages(data, 100)

function addPercentages(dataset, fixedSum) {
   const flatData = Object.values(data).flat();
   const dataCounter = flatData.length;
   const percentages = randomNumbersWithFixedSum(random(1, dataCounter), fixedSum)

   // and here?
}
```

I don't know how to start. Maybe have I to use a `reduce` but how?

Answer (score 0):

We could use lodash [_.range](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#range) and [_.shuffle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#shuffle) to do this, we create random numbers with the remaining sum using Array.map.

We then run through each path we wish to set, reducing the `sum` value allowable on each iteration.

```js
const data = {
  catA: {
    color: ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'gold'],
    animal: ['cat', 'dog', 'hamster'],
  },
  catB: {
    city: ['Sydney', 'Paris', 'Rome', 'London', 'Tokyo', 'Delhi', 'Cairo']
  }
}

// Add a last item argument to tell the function to use all the remaining sum input.
function randomNumbersWithFixedSum(input, sum, multiplier, lastItem) {
    return _.shuffle(_.range(input.length).map((n, i) => {
         const result = (i === input.length-1) && lastItem ? sum: Math.floor(Math.random() * (sum))
         sum -= result;
         return result;
    })).map((x,i) => [input[i], x * multiplier]);
}
   
function getArrayPaths(obj, keys = [], paths = []) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => { 
        if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
            paths.push([...keys, key].join("."))
        } else if (typeof obj === 'object') {
            getArrayPaths(obj[key], [...keys, key], paths)
        }
    })
    return paths;
}

let sum = 100;
let paths = getArrayPaths(data);
let result = paths.reduce((acc, path, i) => { 
    let arr = _.get(acc, path);
    let newArr = randomNumbersWithFixedSum(arr, sum, 1, i === paths.length -1);
    // Reduce our remaining sum...
    sum -= _.sum(newArr.map(a => a[1]));
    _.set(acc, path, newArr);
    return acc;
}, data);


console.log("Result:", result);
console.log("Remaining sum:", sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Terry but this is not what I need. I need the same `data` structure

Comment: Mmm no, note that your sum is much more than 100

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty straightforward `reduce()` that uses recursion to traverse your passed `dataset`. For each property that is an object (but not an array) it recurses, on the way back up it `filters()` out properties that are arrays, sums their total length and generates an array of 'percentages'. It then iterates each array property and `splices` off the required number of percentages and zips them into the property.

```js
function randomNumbersWithFixedSum(quantity, sum) {
  let
    randArr = Array.from({ length: quantity }, () => Math.random()),
    randTotal = randArr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0),
    resultSum = 0,
    percent = n => Math.floor((n / randTotal) * sum);

  return randArr.map((n, i) => i === quantity - 1 ? sum - resultSum : (resultSum += percent(n), percent(n)));
}

function addPercentages(dataset, fixedSum) {
  const zip = (a, b) => a.map((k, i) => [k, b[i]]);

  return Object.keys(dataset).reduce((acc, key) => {
    let element = dataset[key];

    if (typeof element === 'object' && !Array.isArray(element)) {
      element = addPercentages(element, fixedSum);

      const
        arrays = Object.entries(element).filter(([, e]) => Array.isArray(e)),
        arraysTotalLength = arrays.reduce((a, [, { length }]) => a + length, 0),
        randomData = randomNumbersWithFixedSum(arraysTotalLength, fixedSum);

      for (const [_key, array] of arrays) {
        const r = randomData.splice(0, array.length);
        element[_key] = zip(array, r);
      }
    }

    return acc[key] = element, acc;
  }, {});
}

const
  data = { catA: { id: 1, color: ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'gold'], animal: ['cat', 'dog', 'hamster'], catC: { id: 3, fish: ['cod', 'halibut', 'monkfish'] } }, catB: { id: 2, city: ['Syndey', 'Paris', 'Rome', 'London', 'Tokyo', 'Delhi', 'Cairo'] } },
  result = addPercentages(data, 100);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

this will do the job for you. all you need to do is to change the "Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1" which output a random number,with your desired values

```js
function alternate(data) {
    return Object.keys(data).reduce((p, c) => ({
            ...p,
            [c]: Object.keys(data[c]).reduce((pr, cu) => ({
                    ...pr,
                    [cu]: data[c][cu].map(i => ([i, Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1]))
                })

                , {})
        })
        , {})
}


const data = {
  catA: {
    color: ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'gold'],
    animal: ['cat', 'dog', 'hamster'],
  },
  catB: {
    city: ['Syndey', 'Paris', 'Rome', 'London', 'Tokyo', 'Delhi', 'Cairo']
  }
}

console.log(alternate(data))
```

Comment: Thank you but the "total sum of `data`" should be 100